# Create a primary key in databricks delta table using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create an online table in databricks from a delta table. However according to the documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/online-tables.html) I need the delta table to have a primary key for it to work.

I create the delta table currently using the following code in python. How can I adapt it to create a primary key as well so that I am allowed to create an online table using the delta table?

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("my_delta_table")
```